# .htaccess redirect all http to https and one the other way

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all requests but one to https, and that one if accessed with https should be redirected to http. Additionally I'm need standard php rewrite so all lands in index.php . Redirecting all to https is easy. 
I can make it work one way https -> http, but if I uncomment those lines I will get redirected 
from http://example.com/bye to https://example.com/index.php . What am I missing ?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bye$
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bye$
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `THE_REQUEST` variable instead since `REQUEST_URI` variable changes to `/index.php` by your very last rule.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+bye/?[?\s]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+bye/?[?\s]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Thanks, but still if i type https://example.com/bye i won't get redirected to http://example.com/bye

Comment: That is due to your browser cache. Test in a new browser or clear browser cache.

Comment: Nope, tested on 3 different browsers, cache clear ... . Of course I uncommented that rule ..

Comment: Ah there was a regex issue. It is fixed now, try again.